# Google maps API multiple markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to push some markers into google maps using the following code. But it does not seem working. The map is getting centred to the right position but the I can see the markers.

```
var points = [<asp:literal runat="server" id="litPoints"/>];

    $(document).ready(function () {
       var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<asp:literal runat="server" id="litMapCentre"/>);
           var options = {
               zoom:<asp:literal runat="server" id="litZoomLevel"/>, 
                center: mapCenter,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };


        var map = new google.maps.Map($("#monitorMap")[0], options);        
        GetMap(map, points);
    });






    function GetMap(map, mappoints) {       

        var image=new google.maps.MarkerImage('../Images/map/iconr.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(20,32),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0)); 

        for(var i=1; i < points.length; i++) {
            var m=points[i];

            var mylatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(m[0], m[1]);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mylatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image}); 
         }    
}
```

Comment: Accept your recent questions !

Answer (score 0):

Change the second function to be like this:

```
function GetMap(map, mappoints) {       

        var image=new google.maps.MarkerImage('../Images/map/iconr.png',
                    new google.maps.Size(20,32),
                    new google.maps.Point(0,0)); 

        for(var i=0; i < mappoints.length; i++) {
            var m=mappoints[i];

            var mylatlng=new google.maps.LatLng(m[0], m[1]);
            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                position: mylatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: image}); 
         }
```

You were creating a variable called mappoints, but then referring to it as points.  Also javascript arrays are zero-indexed, so if looping over them you usually need to start at 0, not 1.